# Asking for log in when ive not set one

Tags: login

Completely new to this and I've just installed ubuntu 20.04 to an sd card and started up my raspberry pi however it wants a username and password but I never set one up.

There is also an issue where I cannot type in the password section.

Any help is appreciated

Cheers,
Cameron

**Solved**

Comment: You did set user name and password when install. Do it again and you'll see. Why can't you type? Someone is holding your hands?

Comment: https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/how-to-install-ubuntu-on-your-raspberry-pi. The answer to your question is in Step 4. Note that when typing a password on your screen THE CURSOR WON'T MOVE. Just type it anyway. That's normal and expected behavior.

Comment: I've not got to the GUI, I literally formatted the SD card, installed ubuntu and booted it up. Stuck in CLI asking for a log in. Reason I cannot type I don't know the input for the username enters fine but the password section does not accept it.

Comment: Thank you user535733